# Using invoke-command with register-scheduledjob and passing parameters: nested -argumentlist?

Tags: powershell, remote-server

I'm trying to script scheduling a job that will create a new user on a remote machine that I can **only** access via remote powershell session. This is a section of what I've come up with (I might not have shown the declaration of all variables but please assume they're done!):

```
$startTime=get-date
$psoption=new-pssessionoption -skiprevocationcheck
$cusName = $UserCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().username
$cusPassPlain = $UserCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().password
$cusPass = ConvertTo-SecureString "$cusPassPlain" -AsPlainText -Force
$endTime=$startTime.addhours($ExpiresInHours)
$guid=new-guid
$jobTrigger=new-jobTrigger -once -at $startTime

register-scheduledjob -name "$guid" -trigger $jobTrigger -scriptblock { invoke-command -sessionoption $args[0] -computername $args[1] -credential $args[2] -usessl -scriptblock { new-localuser -AccountExpires $args[0] -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword -Password $args[1] -description "Management Account: do not modify" -name $args[2]} -argumentlist $endTime,$cusPass,$cusName } -argumentlist $psoption,$managementURL,userCreds
```

The job is registered correctly but gets stuck in a "running" state. I've tried a few different combinations of code / variables and from that I'm assuming that the argumentlist for the invoke-command scriptblock aren't being passed to the new-localuser command.

This kind of makes sense to me, since my variables are outside of that section, but I have no idea how to get them into the invoke-command! Is it possible? Or is there another method I should be using?

Thanks for taking the time!

[edit]

I thought defining a scriptblock object containing the new-localuser command would be the answer I was looking for, but so far I haven't come up with something that works. I tried

```
$invokeBlock = [scriptblock]::Create("new-localuser -AccountExpires $endTime -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword -Password $cusPass -description 'Management Account: do not modify' -name $cusName")
register-scheduledjob -name "remote_azure_$vmName_$guid" -trigger $jobTrigger -scriptblock { invoke-command -sessionoption $args[0] -computername $args[1] -credential $args[2] -usessl -scriptblock $args[3]} -argumentlist $psoption,$managementURL,$userCreds,$invokeBlock
```

But it seems I can't pass a secure string into the scriptblock :(

Answer (score 0):

It's not strictly an answer to my question about nesting script blocks, but got around my problem by building a scriptblock to use with register_scheduledjob, which called a separate script to perform the other actions.